# Is ubuntu installed in my pc? if yes how can i run it?

Tags: installed-programs

I have purchased a Dell Inspiron pc with windows 7 installed and on the pc there is logo of ubuntu is ubuntu pre installed on my pc. How can I run it

Comment: We cannot really know what was installed on your purchased pc. Do you see the logo on boot of the machine? is it a sticker on the box? Even if it came pre-installed, unless I know where it came from (and trust the source), I'd opt to re-install an OS myself anyway so I know what's on it (and what's been done to it).

Comment: no I do not see the ubuntu logo on the boot of the machine

Comment: yea it is the sticker on the box

Comment: You can download Ubuntu from ubuntu.com (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), write it to thumb-drive or other install media (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016) then try it before installing it (  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014)  Same applies to flavors of Ubuntu too (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu might have been pre installed then wiped and installed Windows 7. Depends where you have purchased the laptop. If Ubuntu was installed alongside Windows, Windows would ask you what operating system to boot. It would look something like this [Windows 7 dual boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k73YX.png)